# Fit timeseries data to model in Matlab

Tags: matlab, regression

I need to fit 108 sets of 18 time points to the following models in Matlab:

```
x(t)=c_0+c_11x(t-1)+e_1t
y(t)=d_0+d_21y(t-1)+e_2t
```

and

```
x(t)=a_0+a_11x(t-1)+b_11y(t-1)+E_1t
y(t)=a_0+a_21x(t-1)+b_21y(t-1)+E_2t
```

where the e/E's are the noise terms.

How would I go about doing that? I've attempted to search but I'm not sure what exactly to call this problem. My endgoal is to work out the Grander causality coefficients.

Comment: suppose you will find something in the [system identification toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/functionlist.html) - and it's "Granger causality" - "Grander" is some parapsychological nut.

Comment: Oops, typo sorry. I'll take a look, thanks.